# Method errors during before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm sure I am just missing something simple, but have been racking my brain for the past few days over this.

I have a Booking and Review table, where the Booking has many Reviews. I can create the Review, but run through an error when trying to define roles of the user leaving and receiving the review.

Here are my models. The Review

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :define_review_role
  after_create :call_update_rating

  belongs_to :booking

  belongs_to :client, class_name: "User", primary_key: "client_id"
  belongs_to :talent, class_name: "User", primary_key: "talent_id"

  def define_review_role
    if review_sender_id === self.booking.client_id
      review_receiver_id = self.booking.talent_id
    else
      review_receiver_id = self.booking.client_id
    end
    self.update
  end

  def call_update_rating
    user = User.find(self.review_receiver_id)
    if review_receiver_id == self.booking.talent_id
      user.update_talent_rating(self.rating)
    else
      user.update_client_rating(self.rating)
    end
    user.save
  end
end
```

And the Booking model

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Start Validations
  validates :amount, format: {with: /(\d{1,3})(\.\d{1,2})?/, :message => "field is invalid. Please enter a correct amount."}

  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :client, class_name: "User", primary_key: "client_id"
  belongs_to :talent, class_name: "User", primary_key: "talent_id"

  has_many :reviews

  has_many :sent_reviews, class_name: "Review", primary_key: "talent_id"
  has_many :received_reviews, class_name: "Review", primary_key: "client_id"

  def client
    User.find(client_id)
  end

  def talent
    User.find(talent_id)
  end
end
```

I have been able to create the review just fine, and upon inspection I am finding that the review.review_receiver_id is being left blank. The define_review_role for some reason is not running, I have tried with before_create, after_save, after_create and no dice.

I know that this is not running because upon inspection, the review_receiver_id is being left blank.

I am also able to access the information through review.booking.talent_id, and review.booking.client_id, so the connections are there. I know I must be missing something but have no idea what.

Comment: Try to change `self.update` to `self.update_attributes(review_receiver_id: review_receiver_id)`

Comment: What is the purpose of `review_sender_id`? Where is it defined?

Comment: I use the receiver_id to display user ratings. I created it in this way so users that are associated with the individual booking can only leave messages.

Comment: Also, the self.update_attributes(review_receiver_id: review_receiver_id) throws me into a loop

Comment: I use the receiver_sender_id to know who is sending the review. I created it in this way so users that are associated with the individual booking can only leave messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `define_review_role` running you only have badly written code. It should probably look something like this

```
def define_review_role
  if review_sender_id === self.booking.client_id
    self.review_receiver_id = self.booking.talent_id
  else
    self.review_receiver_id = self.booking.client_id
  end
end
```

If you try to assign value without `self` the value is assigned to newly created local method instead of attribute of your `Report` class.

You also cannot call `save` or `update` on the end of this method because you are calling it with `before_save` callback. Methods `save` and `update` trigger it again and method gonna be called again and you create infinity loop.

Comment: Thanks!! I knew it was something with the code itself, just not sure where. I appreciate your help!!

Comment: If you want to assign ActiveRecord attribute inside the instance of Review class  (or any other class). You have to always use `self.attribute = 'value'`. If you do it without `self` Ruby creates only local variable and `self.attribute` will still be blank or with old value.